# How Can I Prevent Showing Duplicate In foreach loop At Laravel Blade File?

Tags: php, laravel, loops, foreach, code-duplication

This is my view blade file:

[image: 1]
And this is my table data:

[image: 2]

This is my view code :

```
<form action="" method="post">
@csrf
@foreach($options as $opt)

 <label for="siteName">site name</label>
 <input type="text" id="siteName" name="siteName" value="{{$opt->o_name('siteName')}}">

 <label for="siteURL">site url</label>
 <input type="text" id="siteURL" name="siteURL" value="{{$opt->o_name('siteURL')}}">

@endforeach

 <input type="submit" value="save">
</form>
```

This is my controller code:

```
public function viewOptions()
{
    $options = Option::all();
    return view('view/options', compact('options'));
}
```

This is my class code:

```
protected $guarded = [];

public function o_name($val)
{
      $valss = DB::table('options')
                   ->select('o_value')
                   ->where('o_name', '=', $val)
                   ->first();
      return $valss->o_value;
}
```

**I want to show once in view not duplicate Data and inputs form@ 
How can I do this? what's the problem with my cods?**

Comment: It happens because you are loop through collection of Option.

Comment: try with this `Option::all()->first()`

Comment: @MaulikShah it says ```Call to a member function o_name() on boolean``` when i use ```Option::all()->first()```

Comment: Try this one in your controller code: `Option::select('*')->first();`

Comment: @HirenGohel  it says ```Call to a member function o_name() on boolean``` when i use ```Option::select('*')->first();``` i think it's related to class method o_name

Comment: Yes, in your class, you need to select it using; `->select('o_value', 'o_name')` and then it works!

Comment: try after removing foreach loop because you already get one record from controller

Comment: @AminArjmand: Have you fixed it now?

Comment: @HirenGohel Again ```Call to a member function o_name() on boolean```

Comment: @MaulikShah after removing foreach loop it says : ```Undefined variable: opt (View:...) ```

Comment: @MaulikShah @HirenGohel , I think the problem is ```o_name``` method on option class this method fetch ```o_value``` by passing ```o_name(unique)``` value in view.blade file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think because you use two input in your `@foreach` and your foreach loop 2 times..

try this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
@csrf
@foreach($options as $opt)

 <label for="{{ $opt->o_name }}">{{ $opt->o_name }}</label>
 <input type="text" id="{{ $opt->o_name }}" name="{{ $opt->o_name }}" value="{{ $opt->o_value }}">

@endforeach

 <input type="submit" value="save">
</form>
```

**Update:**

if you want to get specific rows, you can just get them you want then pass into view

```
$options = DB::table('options')
                ->where('o_name', 'siteName')
                ->orWhere('o_name', 'siteUrl')
                ->get();
```

or wite query builder:

```
$options = Option::where(function ($q) {
     $q->where('o_name', 'siteName')->orWhere('o_name', 'siteUrl');
})->get();
```

another way is using laravel Scopes

Comment: Your code is ok, but i want to show o_value by passing o_name value in view.blade file , not load all of rows in option table@

Comment: is there any way to show custom input label name instead of table o_name name ? for example in row o_name is siteName on table but I want to show in view , Site Title on input label? please send me msg on telegram id>>Sibche2013

Comment: I've used laravel localization for custom labels name

Answer (score 0):

Update your controller code and replace

```
$options = Option::all();
```

with

```
$options_all = Option::all();
$options=$options_all[0];
```

the new code will look like this

```
public function viewOptions(){
    $options_all = Option::all();
    $options=$options_all[0];
    return view('view/options', compact('options'));
}
```

Comment: with new controller code it says : ```Call to a member function o_name() on boolean```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
 <label for="siteName">site name</label>
 <input type="text" id="siteName" name="siteName" value="{{$option->o_name('siteName')}}">

 <label for="siteURL">site url</label>
 <input type="text" id="siteURL" name="siteURL" value="{{$option->o_name('siteURL')}}">
```

Controller

```
public function viewOptions()
{
    $option = Option::all()->first();
    return view('view/options', compact('option'));
}
```

Comment: dd your $valss .

Comment: with your code with ```{{$option->o_name('siteName')}}``` on value it prints like this image >> [1](https://i.imgur.com/bS9OzJl.png)

Comment: dd $valss return this ::: ```{#281
  +"o_value": "name"
}```

Comment: I don't know why this happening but when you dd options it has only single data but still it print this many times.